# actions on google simulator - not getting consistent user_id

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm currently testing an action on the 'Actions on Google Simulator'. I wanted to test repeat interactions from a single user. However I've noticed in the response that I'm getting a new user_id every time I interact with the simulator (even if it's during what I would consider the same session e.g I haven't closed and re-opened the simulator). Should I be getting a different user_id everytime? I'm logged in with the same Google account so I'm not sure if it's just the behaviour of the simulator that does this. If so I think it makes it quite difficult to test return user scenarios.

As far as I'm aware the user_id should be consistent, it's just the session_id that should change.

Anyone know if there's any settings anywhere that allow us to change this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm - what you're seeing is that the userId matches the sessionId, right?

This is, apparently, a known bug. See https://plus.google.com/110898804135091598264/posts/Fq2nPf348RC and https://plus.google.com/106388945980545554528/posts/GuVyz2UzFF7 for some discussion about it.

Answer (score 3):

To add to above comment, it right it's a known issue. But in real case scenario(i.e. when you app is in production) userId is a unique id which is specific to user and also if user have multiple devices, the userId will be same. So if you have any logic based on userId you can go ahead with it and in production it will work as expected.